# Is there any AS collection framework that can used in ComboBox and DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, collections

I know AS3Commons-collection framework is a good one, but it can't use in `ComboBox`, recently
I try to use `LinkedSet` data structure to retrieve and store data in `ComboBox`, any one can help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [ListCollectionView](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html)?  Is there a reason not to use it's children, the [ArrayCollection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html) or [XMLListcollections](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/XMLListCollection.html)?

What other features would you be looking for in a collection framework?

Comment: I want use LinkedSet data structure, because I will use LinkedSet to store and retrieve thousand of data, and LinkedSet has the ability of check if the data is duplicate, ArrayCollection's performance is bad, LinkedSet in  AS3Commons-collection framework has a good performance and meet my requirements， but it can't work in ComboBox or DataGrid(ComboBox limit the dataProvider type)

Comment: I'd be cautious about loading thousands of data elements into memory for the app.  You might want to investigate a server side piece that supports some kind of data paging.  I believe LiveCycle offers this.  You may also consider creating a LinkedSetCollection class that extends the ListCollectionView, but uses the LinkedSet as a source. Then you can probably use it as a dataProvider to the ComboBox and DataGrid.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com. Creating a LinkedSetCollection class that extends the ListCollectionView, but uses the LinkedSet as a source.This may works, I will try it, if there is any issue, I hope you can give some advice, thx

Comment: Your best bet is to look at code for ArrayCollection and XMLListCollection and then use the same approach.  But, if you have further questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope I can do it

Comment: @www,Flextras.com. I have to implements IList interface, but function such as getItemAt(index:int,prefench:int = 0) has a index pram, how can I wrapper to my LinkedSet function getItem(node:LinkedNode), you know that LinkedSet doesn't have index maintain, how to add

Comment: You'll have to decide that for yourself. You can easily add in the method signature with no implementation.  Or you can always add items tot he end of the [or beginning] of the list, ignoring the index parameter.